# how to use recursion in javascript class?

Tags: javascript, oop, data-structures

```
class Tasks {
    constructor () {
        this.store = [];
    }

    addTask(taskName) {
        var task = {
        id: +Date.now(),
        task: taskName,
        children: []
            }
        this.store.push(task);
    }

    deleteTask(id) {
       this.store = this.store.filter(function(task) {return task.id! != 
       id});
    }
}
```

Currently I have this code. I access it by `var todos = new Tasks();`
adding `todos.add('Do something');`
`todods.delete(id);`
This works for non nested tasks. I want to use this for nested tasks/todos.

I want to access the store in delete add methods so I can add or delete sub tasks recursively.

strore will look like this

```
nestedArr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        task: 'task 1',
        children[]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        task: 'task 2',
        children [
            {
                id: 3,
                task: 'task 1',
                children[]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                task: 'task 2',
                children [
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        task: 'task 1',
                        children[]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 6,
                        task: 'task 2',
                        children []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

like I can do these using functions, but I want to use this in classes

```
deleteTask(arr, id) {      .....      
  this.deleteTask(arr.children, id) {          ... }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `store` should look like after an example call? Where in the process of writing your code are you stuck?

Comment: Not enough information. Why this structure if you will need to potentially check *every* nested array to find the target? And when *adding*, how will you determine where exactly to add it? Most importantly, what is the problem?

Comment: `add (id) {}` like this @trincot I mean this structure I can strore in a database and can call via API so following the JSON structure. How to recurse an array which is defined like this.store = [];

we can't call it in method like delete (id, this.stroe) {}
This gives an error @SebastianSimon

Comment: This doesn't really address the points I raised in my comment.

Comment: @trincot My task is to use classes and have a nested array inside that class and do all the operations like add delete and update. By using functions I can use `delete (id, store) {
filter the array and remove the task from the array using recursion}` but in class I cannot acces the store like `delete (id, this.store) {} `this giving me an error. I can access the store only inside `delete (id) { this.store.filer(...)}` but this method only find top level objects and not nested ones. to add or to delete I must use recursion so for adding or deleting nested items.

Comment: Sure, but that is not what I am asking about. Maybe edit your question, include your code, focusing on that error, so we can reproduce it. Drop the other questions about `add`. A question here should be about one problem only, so focus on your `delete` function (provide its code), how you call it, and which error message you got, and what you did to debug it.

Comment: I have updated the question. When I want to pass the store as a parameter like `addTask(taskName, this.store){}` but it is showing like `',' expected` and highlighted red in VS code @trincot

Comment: Your question is still asking about `add` and `delete`: you should be asking only one question.

Comment: @yogis75 `this.store` is not a valid parameter name. Look into the syntax of [functions](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) again. Why would you ever _need_ `this.store` as a parameter?

Comment: `//delete selected object (nested)
function deletePage(obj, id) {
  lists = obj.filter((item) => {
    if (item.subTasks !== null) {
      item.subTasks = deletePage(item.subTasks, id);
    }
    return item.id !== id;
  });
  return lists;
}` This is the same function that finds any nested object and deletes it. So, I want to do the same in class method. Here in above function, I can pass the store as obj so I can pass obj.children inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would instead structure the store like this, and have all tasks have "parent" as a property (-1 if they don't have a parent). The children array should contain the ids of it's children.

If you want to remove some items based on `task`, just do it in the following order:

1. Loop through all items to find one or more matches.
2. Remove all children for the tasks that are removed.
3. If having a parent id, remove it from the `children` array if the parent still exist.
4. Remove the task itself.

```js
nestedArr = [{
    id: 1,
    task: 'task 1',
    parent: -1,
    children: []
  }, {
    id: 2,
    task: 'task 2',
    parent: -1,
    children: [3]
  }, {
    id: 3,
    task: 'task 1',
    parent: 2,
    children: []
  }, {
    id: 4,
    task: 'task 2',
    parent: -1,
    children: [5, 6]
  }, {
    id: 5,
    task: 'task 1',
    parent: 4,
    children: []
  }, {
    id: 6,
    task: 'task 2',
    parent: 4,
    children: []
  }
]
```

Comment: `nestedArr = [{
    id: 1,
    task: 'task 1',
    parent: null,
  }, {
    id: 2,
    task: 'task 2',
    parent: null;
  }, {
    id: 3,
    task: 'task 1',
    parent: 2,
  }, {
    id: 4,
    task: 'task 2',
    parent: 2
  }, {
    id: 5,
    task: 'task 1',
    parent: 4
  }, {
    id: 6,
    task: 'task 2',
    parent: 4
  }
]` currently using this structure and I can do all the operations. But my task is to use recursion in class.